# Loading external swf uses old code?

Tags: actionscript-3, class, flash, loader

I'm having an issue running a swf within another. It seems to be running an incorrect version of the code. Here is an explanation of the environment.

a.swf (Document class: ClassA()) loads in b.swf (Document class: ClassB()) via typical loading methods:

`var _loader:Loader = new Loader();

addChild(_loader);

//add relevant event listeners...

_loader.load(new URLRequest("b.swf"))`

Right now, the constructor of ClassB is as such:
`public function ClassB()

{

    trace("ClassB() version 1.0");

}`

If I publish both a.swf and b.swf, load b.swf into a.swf, I get the trace "ClassB() version 1.0"

Now, if I update ClassB() to `trace("ClassB() version 1.1")` and **only** publish b.swf, then run a.swf, I would expect that the output would be "ClassB() version 1.1," however, it is still "ClassB() version 1.0"!

I am not sure what is happening.

a.swf is definitely loading the new version of b.swf (I changed the objects on the stage in b.swf, which is added as a child of ClassA(), so those changes show)...but it is still running the old (1.0) version of ClassB's code. I also verified this by running b.swf on its own, and it shows 1.1

I can get it to run the 1.1 version of ClassB if I **also** republish a.swf

The first thing I can think of is that ClassA and ClassB share the same class path, so when I publish a.swf, it contains the version of ClassB that was created at that time (1.0) and then runs *that* version (instead of the new/1.1 version inside b.swf). Is that correct? Is there a way to avoid this while keeping them on the same class path? Or is something else the issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think that sharing class paths means much. Do you have any references to ClassB inside of a.swf? You could read about application domain to understand how loading class definitions from one swf into another work. http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/system/ApplicationDomain.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. Very informative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible if A.swf has a copy of `ClassB` compiled into it. By default, B.swf will be loaded into a child of A's `ApplicationDomain`. This means that if there are conflicting class definition (in this case, `ClassB`), then the **parent's** definition will be used. If the old ClassB version was also compiled into A.swf, then that version of the class will be used. This could happen easily if the files share the same class path.

As goliatone points out, check to see if you have any references to ClassB inside A.swf--for example, `var foo:ClassB`. This would cause ClassB to be compiled into A.swf. You can also verify this in the Flash IDE by checking "Generate size report" in Publish Properties->Flash.

You probably don't want to compile `ClassB` into A, anyway, if you are trying to load ClassB in dynamically as a module. To not compile `ClassB` in A.swf, you can explicitly tell the compiler not to include ClassB in A.swf. You can do this by adding `-externs ClassB` to the mxmlc command line. Flash Builder, FlashDevelop, etc. have this option in the project properties.

Alternatively, you could remove all references to `ClassB` in A.swf. If you have to instantiate it, do so indirectly: `new (_loader.contentLoaderInfo.applicationDomain.getDefinition("ClassB") as Class)`

You could also load B.swf into its own, separate ApplicationDomain: `_loader.load(url, new LoaderContext(false, new ApplicationDomain());` This will cause the conflicting definitions to exist separately in their own domains.

Comment: Thank you! Very informative. Your last solution (`_loader.load(url, new LoaderContext(false, new ApplicationDomain());`) is the one I ended up using and it works like a charm!

Comment: Also, it would be a good idea to use interfaces. If you need to use ClassB inside ClassA, you can have ClassB implement an interface, say IClassB, and then following Mike Welsh code you would do b:IClassB = new (....getDefinition("ClassB") as Class)  Has many benefits, the easiest one to see is code completion in any IDE that provides it for custom classes.

Comment: Thanks, but I never intended for ClassB to be used in a.swf. It was at one point, but no longer. Thanks for the tip on interfaces though.  @Mike: Is there another option for seeing what classes are being compiled? In Flash CS5, with Size Report on, I'm not seeing the classes compiled. I don't have Flash Builder/Develop, just the IDE (working on a Mac currently)